# IInAppbillingService not generating java, serviceIntent is null

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio, and I am following the In-App Billing tutorial

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

I also checked the tutorial here:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

Both tutorial say I must add IInAppBillingService.aidl to very strict folder structure, I am fairly sure I added it to the correct folder, but I don't think the java file is been generated anyway, at least I haven't seen any.  The effect of this is:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
```

is always returning null.

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Correct package name for this aidl is `com.android.vending.billing`.

Build your application. You should see a generated file named `IInAppBillingService.java` in the `/gen` directory of your project.

Read more at [`Adding the AIDL file to your project`](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-add-aidl)

Comment: Seem to be exactly what I have, even my Import is OK:  import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;

Comment: Do you have `com.android.vending` installed. This is play app. And is it updated?

Comment: OH... nevermind, I found it in app\build\generated\source\aidl\debug\com\android\vending\billing

Comment: Hey, finally managed to break the bad spell and generate the file. The whole problem was in the fact that I created a FOLDER in src/main dir (by right-clicking and creating a new folder), instead of creating an AIDL folder by right clicking on src/main and selecting new/folder/Aidl Folder.. WTF?